# Get all internal links from all pages in a Domain

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am looking for a code which will get all internal links from a website by iterating all internals links [both absolute & relative] found.

So far I managed to write this much, but unable to construct the right logic in the program.

```
import requests, csv, time
from lxml import html
from collections import OrderedDict

links = []
domain = 'bunchball.com'
base_link = 'http://www.bunchball.com/'
unique_list = []

def get_links(base_link):
    r = requests.get(base_link)
    source = html.fromstring(r.content)
    link = source.xpath('//a/@href')
    for each in link:
        each = str(each)
        if domain in each:
            links.append(each)
        elif each.startswith('/'):
            links.append(base_link+each)
            unique_list.append(each)
        else:
            pass

get_links(base_link)

#while 

for each1 in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(links)):
    get_links(each1)
    while each1 not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(each1)
        get_links(each1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with mechanize for a simpler solution:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("http://www.bunchball.com/")
list_of_links=[link for link in br.links()]
```

Comment: i am only looking internal links both [absolute & relative ] , your solution will harvest external links as well & for only 1 introduced url . I want to reach all nested urls within each internal urls foudn.